# Return False not always preventing event

Tags: jquery, wordpress, shortcode

This is code being used in a shortcode on WordPress. Functionality pretty much self explanatory: it's a simple video gallery - click on a playlist box replaces the html of the main video div with the content from one of the hidden divs.

HTML

```
<div class="main-video">
    <iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/50781537" frameborder="0" width="630" height="400"></iframe> 
</div>

    <div id="video-playlist-wrapper">
    <ul class="video-playlist">

    <a href="#"><li><div class="playlist-video-wrapper"><div class="playlist-video-title">Title 1</div><div id="playlist-video1">Desc 1</div></div></li></a>
    <a href="#"><li><div class="playlist-video-wrapper"><div class="playlist-video-title">Title 2</div><div id="playlist-video2">Desc 2</div></div></li></a>
    <a href="#"><li><div class="playlist-video-wrapper"><div class="playlist-video-title">Title 3</div><div id="playlist-video3">Desc 3</div></div></li></a>
    <a href="#"><li><div class="playlist-video-wrapper-last"><div class="playlist-video-title">Title 4</div><div id="playlist-video4">Desc 4</div></div></li></a>
    </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="playlist-video1-content" class="hidden-video"><iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/50781537" frameborder="0" width="630" height="354"></iframe></div>
    <div id="playlist-video2-content" class="hidden-video"><iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/50697289" frameborder="0" width="215" height="130"></iframe></div>
    <div id="playlist-video3-content" class="hidden-video"><iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/50771550" frameborder="0" width="215" height="130"></iframe></div>
    <div id="playlist-video4-content" class="hidden-video"><iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/50750012" frameborder="0" width="215" height="130"></iframe></div>



     </div>
```

JQuery

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $('#playlist-video1').click(function() {
    $('.main-video').html($('#playlist-video1-content').html());
    return false;
    });

    $('#playlist-video2').click(function() {    
    $('.main-video').html($('#playlist-video2-content').html());
    return false;
    });

    $('#playlist-video3').click(function() {    
    $('.main-video').html($('#playlist-video3-content').html());
    return false;
    });

    $('#playlist-video4').click(function() {
    $('.main-video').html($('#playlist-video4-content').html());
    return false;
    });

    });
```

The issue: Sometimes the link event still happens and reloads the page with the href="#" causing a jump to the top of the page and the html is not replaced. Other times it works fine and the main video updates with one of the playlist videos.

Why is this happening? I've looked through the code repeatedly and can't find any errors or issues. When I developed this locally with xampp everything worked fine, there were no issues. Now on the WordPress site it is breaking.

Is it possible the page is already loading too much Jquery and it's taking the Video Gallery jquery too long to load. Any help appreciated! Thanks.

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xjpv2/1/`

Comment: Your example is broken: Vimeo has an error message saying embedding is not allowed for the video.

Comment: Sorry should have noted that I'm aware they don't show on fiddle because its not one of the allowed embed domains . It's fine on my site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kind of an old post I made a while back but figured I'd answer it just in case anyone came along the same issue I was having.

I started from scratch:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(cash) {
    jQuery('.video-playlist a').click(function(e) {
    jQuery('#main-video-iframe').attr('src', jQuery(this).attr('data-url'));
    return false; 
});
```

});

and my HTML (# after vimeo embeds are simply the video IDs):

```
     <div class="main-video">
         <iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/#" id="main-video-iframe"></iframe>
     </div>

 <div id="video-playlist-wrapper">
     <ul class="video-playlist">
        <li>
            <a href="#" data-url="http://player.vimeo.com/video/#">
               <div class="playlist-video-wrapper"></div>
            </a>
        </li>
     </ul> 
 </div>
```

Embarrassed to admit I struggled on this one but I hope it helps someone else down the road.

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
 $('#playlist-video1').click(function() {
    $('.main-video').html($('#playlist-video1-content').html());
    return false;
 });
```

With:

```
 $('#playlist-video1').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.main-video').html($('#playlist-video1-content').html());
 });
```